# Event Macro Throws an Error "Object Required"

Tags: vba, excel, object, events

I have this simple Event Macro, which for some reason throws me an

> Object Required

error on this line `If Not AppDate Is Nothing Then`. Any idea what might be causing this?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim ThisRow As String
    Dim AppDate As Variant
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        AppDate = Target.Value
        If Not AppDate Is Nothing Then
            (...) Recalculate Date in Column F
        Else
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: AppDate = new Target.Value

Comment: you can try `Set AppDate = Target.Value` (not tested)

Comment: @peakpeak I'm getting "User-defined type not defined" error...

Comment: @David -- a tutorial about `Set`. :-)   I have a terriible memory and constantly make mistakes on my _Nothings_  and _Sets_ and such, so I end up cycling through the different syntaxes until it's right.  Then it makes perfect sense... until the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
…
If Not IsEmpty(AppDate) 
…
```

To help clarify, [here is a lengthy tutorial](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1910/Understanding-Null-Empty-Blank-N-A-ZLS-Nothing-Missing.html) **about Nothing**.  <sub>lol</sub>

Comment: You're welcome.  This is reminding me of a Seinfeld episode...  :)

Comment: Yep, writing something about nothing for so many pages requires some talent :)

Answer (score 7):

`Is` operator works with objects and not values.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As New Collection
    Dim z As Object

    x = Target.Value

    If IsEmpty(x) Then
        MsgBox "may be use this."
    End If

    MsgBox TypeName(x)

    If y Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Works"
    End If

    If z Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Works"
    End If

    If x Is Nothing Then '/This won't work

    End If


End Sub
```